# Windows title bar disappears using QDockWidget -- qbackingstore::flush() called with non-exposed window

Tags: qt, opencv, qdockwidget

I encountered a weird problem using QDockWidget:

my essential code:

```
void iMainWindow::createDockWindows()
 {
    camera = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
assert(camera);

QDockWidget *dock = new QDockWidget(tr("2D Camera"), this);
dock->setAllowedAreas(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
pixmapLabel = new MyCameraWindow(camera, dock);//class MyCameraWindow : public QWidget
dock->setWidget(pixmapLabel);
addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, dock);
 }
```

when I run my program, it comes out to be normal

However, if I drag the dock part outside, the windows title bar disappears.

refer : [the image and my explanation](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23084/)

Moreover, after dragging the dock widget outside, the command window shows
qbackingstore::flush() called with non-exposed window

How can I keep the windows title bar after dragging the dock widget outside?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming MyCameraWindow is(or contains) a QGLWidget, you've run into a bug I reported here: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-29359. There is no workaround that I know of(in Qt 5.0.0)